# Can I filter a PivotTable's PivotItems with a selection(s) from a listbox in a Userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a dashboard and I'd like the user to select a product group(s) in a listbox of a userform. I'm having trouble getting the selection of the listbox to filter that specific pivottable's pivotitems. I'd like to understand how to filter pivotitems if a user makes one or multiple selections in a listbox.

I've been at this for hours and I can't seem to connect the listbox and pivottable. I've tried different events and tried executing with a cmdbutton to no avail.

```
Private Sub lbxProduct_Change()

    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
    Set PvtTbl = PvtPage.PivotTables("pvtYoYChart1")

'   I need the pivottable to change whenever a selection is made in the listbox
'   right now, nothing happens when i make a selection
    For Each pvtItm In PvtTbl.PivotFields("Product Group").PivotItems
        If pvtItm <> Me.lbxProduct.Value Then pvtItm.Visible = False
    Next pvtItm

End Sub
```

I expect the user to click an item in a list box and my pivot table to update instantaneously. Thanks a lot for any advice you guys can provide!!

Answer (score 1):

```
        Private Sub ShowItems()
        
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
        
        '== Part 1 - Place the selected elements in an array
        Dim myArray() As Variant
        Dim i As Integer, count As Integer
        Dim msg
        Dim pvtItm As PivotItem
        
        count = 1
        For i = 0 To Lbx_Defaut_TRS.ListCount - 1
            If Lbx_Defaut_TRS.Selected(i) = True Then
                ReDim Preserve myArray(count)
                myArray(count) = Lbx_Defaut_TRS.List(i)
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next i
          
        
        '== Part 2 - Add or remove the PivotItems from the chart
        
        
        With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("DEFAUT")
            For Each pvtItm In .PivotItems
                If IsInArray(pvtItm.Caption, myArray) = False Then
                    pvtItm.Visible = False
                Else
                    pvtItm.Visible = True
                End If
            Next pvtItm
        End With
        
        End Sub
    
 'The IsInArray function used (to check if the elements of the pivot 
'chart are in the array of the selected list ) comes from another post by @BRAD as 'follows 


    '===========================================
    'VERIFICATION IF STRING IS IN ARRAY
    '===========================================
     Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
        Dim i
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
        IsInArray = False
    
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this seems to be more robust

```
Dim showMe, pvtItm

showMe = Me.lbxProduct.Value

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Product Group")
    .PivotItems(showMe).Visible = True '<< first unhide the one we want

    'then hide any others
    For Each pvtItm In .PivotItems
        pvtItm.Visible = (pvtItm.Caption = showMe)
    Next pvtItm
End With
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work. i'm still getting an error.

Comment: apologies, i'm getting an "invalid use of null" error. (94). Thanks.

Comment: Does lbxProduct have a value?

Comment: Hi Tim, not sure what you mean...yes the list box has a list of about 8 products to choose from.

Comment: If you add `Msgbox Me.lbxProduct.Value` before the loop do you see a value?  Note it must match at least one entry in the pivotfield's values, since you can't set all of the entries to hidden.

Comment: Hi Tim, I add the MsgBox before the loop and I get the "invalid use of null" error when I try to select a product in the listbox. Maybe I shouldn't be using a change event? Thanks for your help.