# How do I debug the error: "Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class"?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to be honest. I am pretty unfamiliar with VBA (with the exception of a handful of things) but am generally really good at picking things up quickly and also understanding concepts.

That said, how do I troubleshoot the following code:

```
'error handling to double check time format
    On Error Resume Next
    pvt.PivotFields("Talk Time").CurrentPage = "0:00:00" 'filter talk time
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        pvt.PivotFields("Talk Time").CurrentPage = "12:00:00 AM" 'filter talk time
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For Each itm In pvt.PivotFields("Call Type").PivotItems 'filter call type ('inbound* only')
        If Not itm.Name Like "Inbound ACD*" Then
            itm.Visible = False
        End If
```

The debugger highlights:

```
itm.Visible = False
```

I've been told that this needs to be true. Is there sample coding I could implement that might fix this issue?

I've also been told that this might be due to the Pivot table using the cached pivot items instead of the current one. Supposedly I need to make sure the pivot table does not retain any old items. I do so by right clicking on the pivot table, click on Data tab and set "Number of items to retain per field" to "None". They also gave me the following code if I wanted to do it within VBA:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit=
xlMissingItemsNone
```

This issue was pointed out by a colleague and I seemed to be the only candidate to fix the issue, supposedly the file has been working for months until now. I'm hoping to fix this for good.

Comment: You can't hide all of the items in `PivotItems` - likely you're getting that error because all the other items are already hidden.  First unhide the one you want, then hide the rest. Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56332173/478884

Comment: Or - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786668/unable-to-set-visible-property-of-the-pivotitem-class/66788772#66788772